# Logging violations of rules in limits.conf

Tags: linux, logs, administration, audit

I'm trying to log the details of the programs that where failed due to the limit cap defined in the `limits.conf`. My initial plan was to do it using the **audit** system. The idea was to track the system calls related to limits in the limits.conf that where failed.

However the problem with this approach is that, it's not possible to track the violations of CPU time, since that violation doesn't involve failure of system calls. In the case of CPU time, one thing happens is that the program which violated the CPU time will be delivered a SIGXCPU.

So my questions are:

- How should I go about logging the programs that violated CPU time?
- Also is there any limits.conf specific logs available?

Comment: I can see various places online where there's supposed to be a `printk` to syslog when a limit is bumped into but I'm not able to replicate that behavior on my own so I can't really provide an answer. You may start looking in that direction if you're still interested.